# caffe installation on Mac no cpu with anaconda, library not found for -lboost_python3

Tags: installation, cpu, caffe, boost-python

I hope someone can offer any light on this situation at all, as I have been trying to solve this problem for a whole day and it has been proving a challenge so far!

I am receiving the following error while implementing caffe installation, make all command. Error:

```
LD -o .build_release/lib/libcaffe.so.1.0.0
ld: library not found for -lboost_python3
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [.build_release/lib/libcaffe.so.1.0.0] Error 1
```

I have checked that I have boost installed, and in fact I have boost, boost-python and boost-python3 installed. However I do not know where and how I should specify the path such that to make caffe recognise where the folder is located.

I am trying to specify the path for boost-python3 but it is just not being recognised. My Makefile.config is below, in case it helps. I am trying to install caffe on MacBook Pro without gpu, and to be used with python3.7 and Anaconda. I have installed boost with brew (the all seem to be in Cellar folder, and I also have boost inside my anaconda3 folder, but no boost-python3 there).

By the way, the folder is called boost-python3, but the example Makefile.config uses boost_python3. I assume they mean the same thing and are not messing up my path specification?

```
## Refer to http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/installation.html
# Contributions simplifying and improving our build system are welcome!

# cuDNN acceleration switch (uncomment to build with cuDNN).
# USE_CUDNN := 1

# CPU-only switch (uncomment to build without GPU support).
CPU_ONLY := 1

# uncomment to disable IO dependencies and corresponding data layers
# USE_OPENCV := 0
# USE_LEVELDB := 0
# USE_LMDB := 0
# This code is taken from https://github.com/sh1r0/caffe-android-lib
# USE_HDF5 := 0

# uncomment to allow MDB_NOLOCK when reading LMDB files (only if necessary)
#   You should not set this flag if you will be reading LMDBs with any
#   possibility of simultaneous read and write
# ALLOW_LMDB_NOLOCK := 1

# Uncomment if you're using OpenCV 3
# OPENCV_VERSION := 3

# To customize your choice of compiler, uncomment and set the following.
# N.B. the default for Linux is g++ and the default for OSX is clang++
# CUSTOM_CXX := g++

# CUDA directory contains bin/ and lib/ directories that we need.
CUDA_DIR := /usr/local/cuda
# On Ubuntu 14.04, if cuda tools are installed via
# "sudo apt-get install nvidia-cuda-toolkit" then use this instead:
# CUDA_DIR := /usr

# CUDA architecture setting: going with all of them.
# For CUDA < 6.0, comment the *_50 through *_61 lines for compatibility.
# For CUDA < 8.0, comment the *_60 and *_61 lines for compatibility.
# For CUDA >= 9.0, comment the *_20 and *_21 lines for compatibility.
CUDA_ARCH := -gencode arch=compute_20,code=sm_20 \
        -gencode arch=compute_20,code=sm_21 \
        -gencode arch=compute_30,code=sm_30 \
        -gencode arch=compute_35,code=sm_35 \
        -gencode arch=compute_50,code=sm_50 \
        -gencode arch=compute_52,code=sm_52 \
        -gencode arch=compute_60,code=sm_60 \
        -gencode arch=compute_61,code=sm_61 \
        -gencode arch=compute_61,code=compute_61

# BLAS choice:
# atlas for ATLAS (default)
# mkl for MKL
# open for OpenBlas
BLAS := atlas
# Custom (MKL/ATLAS/OpenBLAS) include and lib directories.
# Leave commented to accept the defaults for your choice of BLAS
# (which should work)!
# BLAS_INCLUDE := /path/to/your/blas
# BLAS_LIB := /path/to/your/blas

# Homebrew puts openblas in a directory that is not on the standard search path
BLAS_INCLUDE := $(shell brew --prefix openblas)/include
BLAS_LIB := $(shell brew --prefix openblas)/lib

# This is required only if you will compile the matlab interface.
```